# Overwrite CSS properties (not a variable)

Tags: bulma

I'm currently working with Bulma CSS and there's something I'm still struggling with. I'm using https://bulma.io/bulma-start/ as my setup.

**Question**:

I'm trying to change the CSS property of a default class (`level-item`) but I'm unsure how to approach that. I find a lot of information how to overwrite variables and that's also mostly what the "[Customize](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/)" section of the documentation talks about.

In my case I want to remove `justify-content: center;` from the `level-item` class but how do I do that? Copy everything from the "default" bulma.css into my custom.css, renaming the class to `level-item-custom` and then assigning this to my element? That doesn't sound correct to me and I would appreciate some guidance.

Thanks!

```
.level-item {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: center; }
```

Currently my files look like this:

**main.scss:**

```
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma";
@import "../css/custom.css";
```

So my final `main.css` file has a `@import url(../css/custom.css);` in there after being generated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have solved this problem by now but for anyone else with the same issue:

You could try adding

```css
.level-item{
    justify-content: flex-start !important;
}
```

into your `main.scss` file before compiling. This will be added into the final css file and would override the bulma value.

([W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp) says that `flex-start` is the default value for `justify-content`)